# Не передается link-url d GTM v2

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Не могу настроить отслеживание кликов по кнопкам в GTM, все что отображается в слое данных - это класс , а класс указанный для ссылки он не видит, соответственно кроме как класс этого спана в переменной и нету

Comment: Будет понятнее, если вы укажете ссылки на используемые технологии (gtm) и предоставите примеры кода.

Comment: Использую gtm.click, пример кода: <div class="ya-share2 ya-share2_inited" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,gplus" data-url="http://,,,,,">
<div class="ya-share2__container ya-share2__container_size_m">
<ul class="ya-share2__list ya-share2__list_direction_horizontal">
<li class="ya-share2__item ya-share2__item_service_vkontakte">
<a class="ya-share2__link" href="http://vk.com/share.php?url=http%3A%2F%2%%%&title=%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3&description=&image=&utm_source=share2" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="ВКонтакте">
<span class="ya-share2__badge">

Comment: <span class="ya-share2__badge">
<span class="ya-share2__icon"></span>
<span class="ya-share2__counter"></span>
</span> В gtm.element.Classes:'ya-share2__icon', больше ничего не попадает

Comment: Это автосгенерированный код, он не сильно приближает нас к решению. Можете в вопросе более подробно сформулировать проблему: чего вы хотите добиться, что происходит на текущий момент? Можно подготовить пример странички, на которой воспроизводится ошибка. Что такое gtm.click, тоже хорошо бы вкратце рассказать.

Comment: Желательно, с примерами кода и данных, потому что фразу "все что отображается в слое данных - это класс , а класс указанный для ссылки он не видит, соответственно кроме как класс этого спана в переменной и нету" вне контекста понять очень непросто.

Comment: gtm.click -это переменная из Google tag manager, в нем нужно фиксировать нажатие пользователя на социальную кнопочку, на данный момент фиксируется нажатие на весь блок соц кнопок, а я хочу мониторить каждую соцсеть отдельно

Comment: gtm автоматически регистрирует события? Может, у него есть API, методы которого можно вызывать вручную?